# pass value between two callback function in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have 2 pushbutton. If i press one infinte loop will be running and if i press other loop must break. please some help in code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Are you using GUIDE or a "programmatic" gui?  The following is a little example for a programmatic gui; similar concepts may apply for GUIDE.  (I personally like the added flexibility of the programmatic gui route, plus I always end up irrevocably breaking any GUIDE gui's I create...)

Anyway, a few things to note in this example:

1. use of the gui's figure handle UserData field to store "global" information.  This is a way to pass data between callbacks.
2. the pause statement within the "infinite" loop is needed so that the interrupt from cb_button2 is processed.  From [Matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/callback-sequencing-and-interruption.html): "If the Interruptible property of the object whose callback is executing is on , the callback can be interrupted. However, it is interrupted only when it, or a function it triggers, calls drawnow, figure, getframe, pause, or waitfor."

   ```
   function my_gui(varargin)

       mainfig = figure;

       out.h_button1 = uicontrol(mainfig,...
                                   'Style','pushbutton',...
                                   'Units','Normalized',...
                                   'Position',[0,0.5,1,0.5],...
                                   'String','Button 1',...
                                   'Callback',@cb_button1);

       out.h_button2 = uicontrol(mainfig,...
                                   'Style','pushbutton',...
                                   'Units','Normalized',...
                                   'Position',[0,0,1,0.5],...
                                   'String','Button 2',...
                                   'Callback',@cb_button2);

       out.button2_flag = 0; %flag indicating whether button 2 has been pressed yet

       set(mainfig,'UserData',out);%store "global" data in mainfig's UserData (for use by callbacks)          


   function cb_button1(varargin)

       out = get(gcbf,'UserData'); %gcbf: handle of calling object's figure

       while ~out.button2_flag
           disp('Aaaahhh, infinite loop! Quick press Button 2!');
           out = get(gcbf,'UserData'); %reload "global" data
           pause(0.1); %need this so this callback may be interrupted by cb_button2
       end

       disp('Thanks!  I thought that would never end!');


   function cb_button2(varargin)
       out = get(gcbf,'UserData'); %gcbf: handle of calling object's figure
       out.button2_flag = 1;
       set(gcbf,'UserData',out); %save changes to "global" data
   ```

Comment: +1 for the displayed messages :-) Well, and for the answer too

Comment: instead of pause() you could set the button's callback to be interuptable. Its just another property of the uicontrol, so you can set it when creating it.